Error when comparing a continuous variable between two independent groups in R
First of all, my background is unrelated to programming and my knowledge on this field is limited.
I am trying to calculate the effect size of the comparison between two independent groups using estimation statistics with the package "dabestr", since this package calculates both ES and 95%CI, and allows you to create a very cool plot. Since i had never used this package I first tried running the code from their GitHub, and everything worked fine. However, when I apply the code to my data an error pops.
With their code everything works nicely
library(dabestr)

# Loading of the dataset
data(non_proportional_data)

# Preparing the data to be plotted
dabest_obj <- load(non_proportional_data,
                   x = Group, y = Measurement,
                   idx = c("Control 1", "Test 1"))


dabest_obj.mean_diff <- cohens_d(dabest_obj)

dabest_obj.mean_diff

The unpaired Cohen's d between Test 1 and Control 1 is 1.245 [95%CI 0.593, 1.984].
The p-value of the two-sided permutation t-test is 0.0022, calculated for legacy purposes only.
5000 bootstrap samples were taken; the confidence interval is bias-corrected and accelerated.
Any p-value reported is the probability of observing the effect size (or greater),
assuming the null hypothesis of zero difference is true.
For each p-value, 5000 reshuffles of the control and test labels were performed. <- Output
Following the instructions from the documentation I tested this code:
library(dabestr)

# Loading of the dataset
data(DatabaseGPhockey)

# Preparing the data to be plotted
dabest_objHOCKEY <- load(DatabaseGPhockey,
                   x = GPTL, y = HAGOSs,
                   idx = c("0", "1"))

#Calculate Effect Size
dabest_obj.mean_diff <- hedges_g(dabest_objHOCKEY,  perm_count = 5000)

Where GPTL is the grouping variable that is either 0 or 1, and HAGOSs is the continuous variable, I run the first section fine with no issue. However, when i try to calculate the ES then this error appears.
"Error in PermutationTest(ctrl_measurement, test_measurement, effect_size = effect_size_type,  :
The two arrays do not have the same length."
Any idea on what is wrong and how could I fix it?
Thanks in advance
Marcos

What version of the package are you using? There seems to be a discussion on this error on the package github repository that could be related to your issue

I´m using this version (2023.9.12)

That's the same version as the one with the errors in the thread I linked. Try to install the latest dev version, following the first block of commands in this post by the package developer. That might fix your issue.
